# Understanding Arbitrary Modulus Indexing

Tags: digital-logic

I'm a hobbyist looking for a way to produce the quotient and remainder for a fixed modulus as efficiently as possible. My initial approach was conventional: find the reciprocal of the modulus, then multiply it by the dividend.

However, I came across a paper, [Arbitrary Modulus Indexing](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/skeckler/pubs/MICRO_2014_Modulus_Indexing.pdf), which introduces a technique to produce the remainder (and quotient) for a fixed modulus. If I'm reading the paper correctly, it is more efficient than a "naive" multiplication by a constant, because it transforms the sum of the partial products into a series of additions that are narrower than the multiplier.

In Part III, the description of the technique begins with two basic cases for moduli with the form 2<sup>N</sup> - 1 and 2<sup>2</sup> + 1), which I think I understand, as examples are provided. However, the full generalization for an arbitrary modulus is completely incomprehensible to me.

More specifically, the binary dividend is partitioned into multiple digits. The radix of these digits is determined the size of the repeating bit pattern of the reciprocal 1 / modulus. In the two basic cases, my understanding is that I can just substitute the digits at the correct positions, and then sum/subtract them, because the repeating bit pattern contains only one bit (or it has after it is expressed in redundant form with the digits {-1, 0, +1}).

However, the reciprocals of arbitrary moduli have bit patterns that contain multiple ones. My understanding is that I'm supposed to multiply each digit with the the bit pattern, but then their products exceed the size of the digits. Then how I'm supposed to sum these products/digits?

My apologies if I'm this is all unclear; my math isn't anywhere near the level sufficient for this sort of thing.

Comment: This could be an interesting question to me. But it sounds as though you want others to read the paper and help you through it. And that's less of a question than ... something else, perhaps. Can you sharpen the question here? (But perhaps someone else will read better than I, and can clarify -- I'm currently thinking about Section 4.6 of `Concrete Mathematics` as part of their discussion on number theory. I do enjoy these kinds of things. But less time for foggier goals.) Best wishes, regardless.